# How can I pipe the output of curl to bc?

Tags: bash, curl, bc, konsole

As part of a larger script, I want to get a numerical value stored in a text file on the web, , then open a terminal window, display that value, and send it to bc so I can interactively do calculations on it.

I came up with this:

```
konsole --hold -e curl http://mysite/num.txt | bc
```

but if I run the part after konsole I get the output

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

If I execute the script containing this line, I get the display of the number from curl, but I think it tries to pipe the entire line (including konsole) to bc, which I believe would only happen once I close the terminal window - so that doesn't help.

How can I get the number into bc? I'd be open to commands other than curl and bc to accomplish this basic goal.

Comment: what do you get when you run `curl http://mysite/num.txt` ?

Comment: That results in the correct output, the contents of that file. Looks like Robin Green nailed the answer already, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
konsole --hold -e bash -c 'cat <(curl --silent -S http://mysite/num.txt) /dev/tty|tee /dev/tty|bc'
```

If `curl http://mysite/num.txt` outputs a new line character at the end, you'd have to remove it.